# How do I remove a tab stop in Google Documents?

Tags: google-docs

I mistakenly added too many tab stops to the ruler in my Google Document, and it's not obvious how to remove them.

How do I remove a tab stop from a Google Document?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To remove a tab stop, simply use your mouse pointer to click-and-drag the tab stop off of the ruler. (Of course, the ruler needs to be visible.)

Unfortunately, I cannot find a "keyboard-only" method to do this.

Comment: There is a "down arrow" that couldn't be dragged away. What's that?

Comment: one must drag it over/under the ruler, when dragging the tab-stop right/left of the rule it gets stuck at the rightmost/leftmost position of the ruler

Answer (score 1):

The tab stop cannot be dragged horizontally off the ruler, but it can be dragged vertically off the ruler.

Answer (score 0):

I could not drag a tab stop that had been created for a hanging indent. The solution was to click in menu on Format > Align & indent > Indentation options > None. This removed the tab stop.